# What challenges are invalidated with Acrophobia?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

Each week, there are new challenges that rotate through.  Examples of non-competitive ones are completing levels with specific time/score constraints, killing enemies with specific weapons, or finding collectibles.

With the addition of 0.0x multiplier skulls like Acrophobia or bandana, these challenges can be made much easier.  I've noticed that "Complete level within X minutes" challenges do not progress with Acrophobia on, but "Kill enemies with snipers" will.

So, as far as challenges related to playing campaign, which ones cannot be achieved with the help of Acrophobia?